# Data binding using a button

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I wanted to bind a list of id to a table but fail to do so:

HTML:

```
  <table>
    <thead><tr><th>ID</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
      <tr><td data-bind="text: id"></td></tr></tbody>
  </table>
  <button id="help">help</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function ViewModel(){
  var array = [];
  this.records = ko.observableArray(array);
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

$("#help").click(function(){
   processClick();
});

function processClick(){
  vm.array([{id: "888888"}]);
}
```

Comment: ` Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in `function processClick(){
  vm.array([{id: "888888"}]);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed code (click on "Run code snippet" to see how it works)

```js
function ViewModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.i = 1;
  this.records = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  this.processClick = function()
  {
    self.records.push({id: self.i++});    
  };
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead><tr><th>ID</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
      <tr><td data-bind="text: id"></td></tr></tbody>
  </table>
  <button id="help" data-bind="click: processClick">help</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You're mixing knockout with DOM manipulation with jQuery. That's a mistake... if you want to make an action to a ViewModel, you need to define it as a function in the ViewModel itself.

Another error was to declare array variable as local for the ViewModel, and then try to access it through a simple javascript function. The fix in your code that makes it work is:

```
function processClick(){
  vm.records.push({id: "888888"});
}
```

That way you are updating the viewModel records observableArray, but I strongly recommend you to isolate the ViewModel from tradicional javascript functions.

Greetings!